# Spray Returning JSON

Tags: spray, spray-json

I've just started using Spray and I'm building a sample API that simply returns some JSON.
Take the following example. I have the alphabet stored in a singleton...

```
class Alphabet {}

object Alphabet {
    final val alphabet = Array('a', 'b', 'c', ...)
}
```

I then have a simple spray route...

```
path("list") {
  get {
    respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
      complete(Alphabet.alphabet)
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine and seems to return an "application/json" response with the correct data. But is this valid? i.e. is this a correctly formatted response that would be expected by an end user?
The reason I ask is I have looked at a number of Spray examples and most seem to use case classes and specify custom JSON formatters similar to this...

```
object CustomJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val responseFormat = jsonFormat3(CaseClassHere)
}

...

complete {
  CaseClassHere("Test", "Test");
}
```

Whats the correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: spray-json already contains some automatic conversions including one that maps a scala.Char to a json string, and a Scala Array to a json array. If that's what your users expect is a question of how you want your api to look like. spray-json can only provide automatic conversions for mappings that are "sufficiently intuitive", you need to care for every else.

Comment: ah ok, so what I am currently returning is automatically being catered for using the default marshalers?

Comment: It looks like it. You don't show it but I guess you have imported `SprayJsonSupport` somewhere. Btw. you don't need `respondWithMediaType(application/json)`